# recursing a list of 73033 elements with HTML tags and get context from it

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a long list of elements with a length of 73,033. I would like to get the context from it. In the list, each element has the same structure (if the block of the following code helps), and it looks like this `<div align="center" class="photocaption"> Author/Designer Carleton Varney with Jim Druckman </div>`.  What I am interested in getting is the text `Author/Designer Carleton Varney with Jim Druckman.`

**Main code**

```
NewSoups = [BeautifulSoup(NewR) for NewR in NewRs]. 
captions = [soup.find_all("div", class_ = "photocaption") for soup in NewSoups]
flattened_captions = []
for x in captions:
    for y in x:
        flattened_captions.append(y)

print(len(flattened_captions)) #73033

import re
results = [re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', y) for y in flattened_captions] #where the error comes from
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "picked.py", line 22, in <module>
results = [re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', y) for y in flattened_captions]
File "/opt/conda/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 155, in sub
return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I am wondering if there is a convenient way to loop through the long list of `<div ></div>`. If not, what would be the best way to extract all text that I desire? Thank you very much.

Comment: Not knowing anything about BeautifulSoup, but I'm guessing that the objects in `flattened_captions` have a `getText()` or `text()` method of some kind that will simply extract the text contents of the divs for you.

Comment: Thanks @Welbog, it showed `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'getText'`, and `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: So the list of captions contains lists representing HTML elements? That doesn't sound right to me. I would try to find documentation on the types returned by `soup.find_all`, because something it returns must have a method for getting elements' text.

Comment: Thank you. I tried a few different things, but they all didn't have the attribute `'text'`, including this one - `captions = [soup.find_all("div", class_ = "photocaption").text for soup in NewSoups]`
`AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'text'`. Did I misunderstand your comment or I could try a different thing? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I believe you are misunderstanding. I do not expect the list of elements to have any text methods, I expect the elements themselves to have text methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am going to post is not the most elegant or efficient way to deal with the posted problem. As Welbog pointed out, BeautifulSoup itself has provided the function of extracting context. As I received the error as I posted my original question, however, I was just curious where the error came from. It turned out that the returned things from flattented_captions were not strings. It's quite simple to solve. Method as below.

```
str_flattened_captions = [str(flattened_captions[i]) for i in range(len(flattened_captions))]

gains = [re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', item) for item in str_flattened_captions]
```

To test

```
print(gains[:5])
r Barbara Schorr ', ' Architect Joan Dineen with Alyson Liss ', ' Author/Designer Carleton Varney with Jim Druckman ', ' Designers Richard Cerrone, Lisa Hyman and Rhonda Eleish (front) in their room called "Holiday Nod To Nature" ']
```